# AWS Elastic Beanstalk not deploying code fixes

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using aws EB to deploy my django app. I use the AWSEBCLI.

Everything works fine but if for some reason I mistakenly deploy broken code the ebcli will never deploy a new corrected version.

I'll have to SSH into the EC2 instance and fix it manually. Why? is there a way to force new code?

For example, I do some edits and I run `git add .` then `git commit -m 'xx'` then `eb deploy`

the result is:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation. 
container_command 01_migrate in .ebextensions/02_python.config failed. 
For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-xxx'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

At this point even if I edit the code, fix the indentation make the new git adds & commits `eb` will always show me this error until I SSH into the instance and I fix it manually.

Only then it will start to accept new commits. I really don't understand why and is rather annoying. Any ideas on how to skip the whole SSH part?

Comment: Have you tried changing the config file name?

Comment: No, but I figure out that deploying it once without container commands and then adding them back work.

Comment: A bit late to he post, but have you tried ensuring there are no tabs in the .ebextensions/* files? This should fix it.